# How to monitor ActiveMQ queue in Apache James

Tags: activemq-classic, james

We're using Apache James 3.0-beta4 which uses embedded ActiveMQ 5.5.0 for FIFO message queue, and sometimes messages get stuck. Therefore, we need to monitor it. Is there any way to monitor an ActiveMQ queue like message size and most recent message-id in the queue (if possible).

In the JAMES `spring-server.xml` I found that:

```xml
    <amq:broker useJmx="true" persistent="true" brokerName="james" dataDirectory="filesystem=file://var/store/activemq/brokers" useShutdownHook="false" schedulerSupport="false" id="broker">
        <amq:destinationPolicy>
            <amq:policyMap>
                <amq:policyEntries>
                    <!-- Support priority handling of messages -->
                    <!-- http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-support-priority-queues.html -->
                    <amq:policyEntry queue=">" prioritizedMessages="true"/>
                </amq:policyEntries>
            </amq:policyMap>
        </amq:destinationPolicy>
        <amq:managementContext>
            <amq:managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </amq:managementContext>
        <amq:persistenceAdapter>
            <amq:amqPersistenceAdapter/>
        </amq:persistenceAdapter>
        <amq:plugins>
            <amq:statisticsBrokerPlugin/>
        </amq:plugins>
        <amq:transportConnectors>
            <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:0" />
        </amq:transportConnectors>
    </amq:broker>
```

also one old part from readme:

```
    - Telnet Management has been removed in favor of JMX with client shell
    - More metrics counters available via JMX
   
...

  * Monitor via JMX (launch any JMX client and connect to URL=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi)
```

which is confusion on how to use it.

This is part of the bigger "monolith" project which now is recreated for microservices but still need to be supported ;) All was fine till mid of March.

Comment: @JustinBertram it uses ActiveMQ for FIFO messages queue and sometimes messages got stuck there so that is why I need to monitor it to see why.

Comment: @JustinBertram correct

Comment: @JustinBertram unfortunately is embedded (as a jar file)

Comment: @JustinBertram that came from an old version 3.0-beta4 (src code 
 here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/james/james-server/3.0-beta4/)

Comment: @JustinBertram because it is part of the bigger "monolith" project which now is recreated for microservices but still need to be supported ;) All was fine till mid of March.

Comment: I think you're unlikely to get any real support on either Apache James 3.0-beta4 or ActiveMQ 5.5.0. Both releases are over _a decade old_ at this point. It's fairly plausible that whatever issue you're facing has been resolved in a subsequent release of _either_ Apache James or ActiveMQ. I **strongly** recommend you upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like ActiveMQ management and monitoring is not possible because [JMX is disabled](https://github.com/apache/james-project/blob/fff209a0f9cd50c35fbec1596c9d6fa261c9d808/server/queue/queue-activemq/src/main/java/org/apache/james/queue/activemq/EmbeddedActiveMQ.java#L98).

Comment: So that means I will need to enable it and recompile JAMES?

Comment: Ideally James would be modified to make this configurable and then in the next release you could enable it. However, if you need to enable it immediately then modifying the code and rebuilding the jar is your only option. Once that is done then you should be able to attach a JMX tool like `JConsole` to the process and inspect queue statistics.

Comment: I have updated OP with some config for JAMES. Not sure if that will help anything.